# Set starting value for Serial Primary Key

Tags: postgresql

Whenever I am creating a table in Postgres, I like using SERIAL as primary key so that I don't do duplicates. But I have not been able to set a starting value for this. Let say I am creating student IDs that all have to be 8 digits, but SERIAL always starts from 1, how can I choose the starting value and then just increment from there? I have looked through the answered questions but I couldn't find the answer. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685389/how-to-specify-the-primary-key-seed-for-a-postgres-table

Comment: The possible solution is insert first record with certain ID. The next records will be inserted with autoincreament.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setval()` to change the sequence and `pg_get_serial_sequence()` to obtain the name of the sequence:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(table_name, column_name), 9999999);
```